# Apple Magic Keyboard four key [4, r, f, v] problem

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard, launchpad

I use MacBook Pro M1 chip 2020 model 16GB RAM, 256 SSD with an Apple magic keyboard [Model - A1644 EMC 2815].

[image: Apple magic keyboard]

The problem is, whenever I typed first time 4, r, f, v or 4, F, R, V it redirect me to the launchpad [image: LaunchPad] instead of typing those words as a text word. It also types the word too. If I type a second time it redirects me back to the type screen.

How to fix it?

Comment: If you open notes, do the keys all work as expected?

Comment: Can you try a different keyboard, or that one with a different machine?

Comment: The obvious cause is a hardware problem with the keyboard, making unable to distinguish the keys in that column (F3, 4, R, F, V). Unless you're skilled at repairing electronics, you'll probably need to get the keyboard repaired or replaced. (And repair may not be possible/economic.) Note that non-Apple keyboards are available much cheaper, though with variable build quality; and that some new Apple keyboards include a Touch ID sensor, which you might find handy.